# mysql full text search strange behaviour with some words

Tags: mysql, sql, full-text-search

In mysql I'm having a column with full text indexing. Search is running fine for everything except for this row

```
ASP.NET and LINQ
```

Any query on the word "asp.net" would never return anything.

i used search strings like below but all would not yield any result -

```
SELECT * FROM job_posts WHERE MATCH(description) AGAINST ('+"asp.*"' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
SELECT * FROM job_posts WHERE MATCH(description) AGAINST ('+"asp.net" +linq' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
SELECT * FROM job_posts WHERE MATCH(description) AGAINST ('+"asp.*" +linq' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
SELECT * FROM job_posts WHERE MATCH(description) AGAINST ('+"asp.net"' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
SELECT * FROM job_posts WHERE MATCH(description) AGAINST ('"ASP.NET"' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

View the online editor [here](https://onecompiler.com/mysql/3yhx44fy2)

the table structure as is below

```
CREATE TABLE `job_posts` (
`job_id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`title` text COLLATE utf8mb4_bin,
`description` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_general_ci,
`state` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
`country` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
`email` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
`city` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`job_id`),
FULLTEXT KEY `full_text` (`description`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin;

insert into job_posts (title, description,state, country, city, email ) values ('.NET Developer' , 'ASP.NET and LINQ' , 44, 2, 7755 , 'xyz');
```

Comment: Period is treated as the end of a word, not as part of a word by default in mysql.

Comment: @Shadow no atleast four words are required for myisam to work. myisam would work with the word "Node.js". "asp.net" works with innodb